# Cannot add anything to MySQL DB using Java + Spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, intellij-idea, postman

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gx4iBLKLVHk&t=3025s) tutorial on YouTube.

At about the 53 minute point in the video, I'm getting an error. Using Postman to test my DB, I get a 500 error when trying to POST something to my DB. The GET works fine, and I can see my (empty) DB but when I try to add a new entry, I get the error.

Stepping through my code in IntelliJ I see the following errors:

> no such instance field: 'requestActive'

and

> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement

I'm new to Java and have no idea what's wrong, as I'm following the tutorial almost exactly. The only changes I've made is using the word "Movie" instead of "Employee" everywhere because I'm going to change the application to something a little different when I'm finished.

**Model**

```
public class Movie implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String jobTitle;
    private String phone;
    private String imageUrl;
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String movieCode;
```

**Repo**

```
public interface MovieRepo extends JpaRepository<Movie, Long> {
    void deleteMovieById(Long id);

    Optional<Movie> findMovieById(Long id);
}
```

**Service**

```
    public Movie addMovie(Movie movie){
        movie.setMovieCode(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        return movieRepo.save(movie);
    }
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/movie")
public class MovieResource {
    private final MovieService movieService;

    public MovieResource(MovieService movieService) {
        this.movieService = movieService;
    }

...

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<Movie> addMovie(@RequestBody Movie movie){
        Movie newMovie = movieService.addMovie(movie);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newMovie, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Here is the whole project (so far) on Github:
https://github.com/nathanreinauer/GenSpark/tree/master/moviemanager

Comment: Your service isn't transactional. Also I reallyl hope those `findMovieById` and `deleteMovieById` methods are going to get removed as those are already in `JpaRepository` (`findById` and `deleteById` to be exact) if they don't I would go for a different tutorial. Please add the **full stacktrace** not just random snippets from the stacktrace.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the full stacktrace in IntelliJ... I don't see any errors unless I step through everything. The postman site doesn't give a stacktrace that I could find, just a 500 error.

Comment: The stacktrace/error is in your logging in your IDE or command line depending on how you run the application.

Comment: Please share the POST request you send from postman.